# java find intersection of a block with a surface in 3D space

Tags: java, 3d, jmonkeyengine

At the moment we have a bunch of 3d blocks (think cubes) that are imported in a JMonkey 2 canvas.

I need to find an intersection of these blocks with a 3D surface that is imported by the user.
The problem is that I have no idea how to do this in JME or any other 3D engine for that matter.

If anyone has any experience using JMonkey for this kind of taks, or maybe you did it using some other 3D engines could you please provide some code hints, maybe links to relevant resources?

edit for clarification: I need to divide the block into 2 shapes: below/above the surface.

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest you post your question also in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com, I came across similar questions there.

Comment: See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/22300/2158

Comment: You will have to provide the type of objects you are using, usually "primitive" shapes like cubes already have good enough collision detection that may or may not work with the "Surface" you're using. Depending on the exact Shape and Surface you can get things like thedistance between them, collision array (not sure of this one), or just to know if they're in a collision state.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to accomplish, just find out IF it intersects or "where" it intersects. It will be easier (mathematically) if your boxes are AABB (axis aligned bounding boxes), that is - aligned with the xyz axis and not rotated. Is this the case?

However, you have support in JME for these kind of tasks. You might want to read this text: http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3:advanced:collision_and_intersection

Comment: Hi Petter, i need to find the "where" it intersects, basically my task is to divide the block into 2 shapes : below/above the surface. I will edit my question and this clarification.

Regarding your question: the blocks are not aligned with the axis. They are imported as a bunch of points and can be rotated at any angle.